# Python, How do I ignore a string such as 'done' amongst numbers to sum the total from a list

Tags: python-3.x

while True:
    numbers = input('> ')
    if numbers == 'done':
        break
total = 0
for number in numbers:
    if numbers == int:
        total = total + numbers
print(total)

Comment: Hi, I suggest in order for you to get better response to write in your post what you want to achieve, not only in the title, also be a little more specific, you can add an example. Formatting your code would be appreciated so users can understand it better

Comment: Hi Nathan, Thanks for the advice, I copied and pasted my code from my editor Im not sure why it ended in that format, looks horrible to read

Comment: Just a hint:  In stackoverflow, to make your code look properly formatted in a post, prepend four spaces in front of every line of code.  Otherwise, stackoverlfow will treat your code like one long paragraph and remove all sorts of formatting from it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a hard time understanding exactley what u want to do with this code, please use a proper code block next time, with proper indentation. My guess is that u want to get a input number like 345 and add 3+4+5 as a output. If the input is not a int it should break the loop. Ive come up with 2 diffrent solutions, depending on what you need.

This code will simply take the input and check if it is "done", if it is not "done" it will try to add. This is a easy to understand solution but it will produce a error if the input is any diffrent string than "done".

```
while True:
numbers = input(">")
if numbers == "done":
    break
else:
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        total += int(number)
print(total)
```

This approach will test for the "done" string again, but afterwards will also check if the input can be converted into a int. if not the error is captured and it will return "invalid input". If u want the programm to terminate at any string u can just put break in  the except section.

```
while True:
numbers = input(">")
if numbers == "done":
    break
else:
    try:
        testing = int(numbers)
        total = 0
        for number in numbers:
            total += int(number)
    except:
        total = "invalid input"
print(total)
```

im a Beginner myself and if a experiencend person can show me a better way to do this i would be very interested

Comment: Hi Athos, Im new to the site so didnt realise i had pasted my code in such a horrendous way,I wrote it and cant even make sense of it

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
numbers = input('> ')
if numbers == 'done':
    break
total = 0
for number in numbers:
    if numbers == int:
        total = total + numbers
print(total)
```

Assuming this as your code:

Here's a solution to your problem-->

```
numbers=[]
while True:
    a=input('>')
    if a=='done':
        break
    else:
        numbers.append(a)
total=0
for number in numbers:
    total = total + int(number)
print(total)
```

By default everything gets accepted as string so we convert it to integer to find total.
Also we use list to store all the values we accept.

Another Solution is-->

```
numbers=[]
while True:
    a=input('>')
    if a=='done':
        break
    else:
        numbers.append(a)
p=map(int,numbers)
print(sum(p))
```

Hope you understand the solution :-)

Comment: YES... this was the method I had in my head but couldnt put it into code, this is awesome thanks, I managed to solve it in a differnt way, I havent come across the Map function Ive seen it mentioned a few times though. Thank you for this

Comment: Pleased to know that you understood and liked it too. If you got it then accept it as solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
total = 0
number_of_inputs = 0

while True:
    number_string = input('Enter a number: ')

    try:
        total += float(number_string)
        number_of_inputs += 1
    except ValueError:
        break  # we weren't given a number, so exit the loop

# Now that we're outside of the loop, print out the total:
print('The total is:', total)

if number_of_inputs > 0:
    average = total / number_of_inputs
    print('The average is:', average)
else:
    print('The average cannot be calculated, as no inputs were given.')
```

Do you see what's happening?  The while loop keeps ask for and adding integers to `total` until a non-integer (like "done") is given.  Once it gets that non-integer, the `int()` function will fail, and the exception it throws will get caught, and the code will immediately `break` out of the `while` loop.

And once out of the loop, the total and the average are printed out.

A few things you should be aware of:

- If the user gave no inputs (which is possible here), the total will correctly print out as 0, but if you try to calculate the average, you will error, due to diving by `number_of_inputs` (which is also 0).  That is why I check that `number_of_inputs` is greater than zero before I even attempt to calculate the average.
- Originally I used `int()` to convert the string to a number, but I changed it to use `float()` instead.  I figure that since you want to calculate an average, averages are not necessarily integers (even if all the inputs are), so there's no point in enforcing integer input.  That is why I changed the `int()` to `float()`, but whether or not you want to use it is up to you.
- `ValueError` isn't a function; it's an `Exception`.  At this point you probably don't know what `Exception`s are, so just know that they are special cases that can happen, and they're often used for catching errors, such as bad input values.

In the code I posted above, the loop is always expecting numerical input.  But as soon as we have input that can't be converted to a number, the program then says, "Hey, I have an *exception* to what we're expecting!  The *exception* is that there's an *error* in the *value*!"  Then the program, instead of continuing to the next line of code (which is `number_of_inputs += 1`) will then execute the block of code under the `except ValueError:` section.  And in the code above, all it does is call `break`, which exits the loop.

Once out of the loop, the code prints out the total and the average.

If it weren't for the `try:` and `except ValueError:` lines in the code, then the program would abruptly end (with a lengthy error message) once someone gave a non-numerical input.  That happens because the call to `float()` wouldn't know how to convert a value like "done" to a number, so it does nothing more than just quitting.

However, by using `try:` and `except ValueError:`, we are anticipating that someone might give non-numerical input.  When that happens (which it will, when the user is finished giving inputs) -- instead of quitting -- we want an alternate action to take.  And we specify that alternate action to be a simple `break` out of the loop -- which will allow the program to continue with whatever is after the loop.

I hope this makes sense.  If it doesn't, it will make more sense once you start learning about Exceptions in Python.

Comment: Hi J-L, thanks, I was trying to do everything in one loop which I have now relised is not great. I havent seen the ValueError function before I'll have to do a bit of research on that one

Comment: Hi, @JamieCarson!  Actually, `ValueError` isn't a function; it's an `Exception`.  I could tell you more about them in this comment, but I added more to my post above.  Go ahead and re-read my post and see if it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
average = 0
count = 0

while True:     
    numbers = input('> ')

    if numbers == 'done': break

    try:     
        total = int(numbers) + total
        count = count + 1
    except:
        print('nope')

    try:
        average = total / count
    except:
        print('error')

print(total)
print(average)
print(count)
```

Comment: So the problem I was trying to solve was to write a program that takes mutiple intergers from user input to calculate the average. The brick wall is when I tried to calculate the answer I kept getting an error as I was calculating str and int, I got there in the end not sure if its the best way to write the program, any feedback would be greatly appreciated